# Can i decline iphone call when the screen was locked AND power button Does not work?

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake

Can any body help? i use iphone 5, the power button does not work, what shall i do to decline the call when the screen was locked? are any software? or some combinations?

Comment: + or - button will throw it to voicemail, or at least silence it.

Answer (score 1):

on your iPhone, go to: settings > general > accessibility > assistive touch
turn it on, it will then put a touchable dot overlay on your screen (even at the lock screen) which will open a popup, allowing you to select "lock screen".

Comment: Thanks so much for answering, but what i need is how to reject call or decline call while the screen locked.

Answer (score -1):

there is a reminder dot on locked screen, it has two options 1. in an hour; 2. when I leave, choice anyone, incoming call will be declined.